# A deduction from $x^n-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{(n-2)/2}[x^2-2x\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Prove that $$x^n-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{(n-2)/2}[x^2-2x\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+1]$$ if $n$ be an even positive integer. Hence deduce that $$\sin{\frac{\pi}{32}}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{32}}\sin{\frac{3\pi}{32}}\cdots\sin{\frac{15\pi}{32}}=\frac{1}{2^{13}}$$

Attempt:

I am able to solve the 1st part of the problem and unable to solve the 2nd part that is the deduction part of the problem. Please help for the deduction part only.

Edit:

Using double angle: I can show that $$\sqrt{n}=2^{(n-1)/2}\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}\sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\cdots \sin{\frac{(n-2)\pi}{2n}}$$

Please suggest suitable n and the please help me to complete the remaining part. I have taken n=32 but not able to complete the solution.

Comment: We can use double angle

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I have used the double angle and edited my problem. Please help me to complete the remaining part

Comment: I have given the answer and also other way

Answer (score 1):

Hint $x=\frac{\pi}{32}$ so we can write it as $(\ sinx\sin(15x))(\sin(2x)\sin(14x))...sin(8x)$ now multiply/divide by $2^7$ and we know $sin(8\pi/32)=1/\sqrt{2}$  then after multiplying we get $\frac{1}{2^7\sqrt{2}}.(\cos(\pi/2)-\cos(7\pi/16)).....(\cos(0)-\cos(\pi/16))$ as $2\sin(a)\sin(b)=\cos(b-a)-\cos(a+b)$ so we get $\frac{1}{2^8}cos(7x)cos(6x)cos(5x)cos(3x)cos(2x)cos(x)$ now again multiply/divide $2^3$ and use $2\cos(a)\cos(b)=\cos(a+b)+cos(a-b)$ then we get $\frac{1}{2^{11}}\cos(3\pi/8)\cos(\pi/4)cos(\pi/8)$ and getting result from here is easy or you can use sin as $R(e^{ix})$ So we can write it as $$\sum e^{inx}$$ where $n\in [1,8]$ and then you have geometric series which can be calculated but maybe it will require a calculator to verify final result

Comment: "we can write it ...."  it means ?

Comment: Means the given equation in a unique pattern to use identities