# How to deduce the following complex number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

> Using the result $$x^n-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{(n-2)/2}[x^2-2x\cos \frac{2k\pi}{n}+1],$$ if $n$ be an even positive integer,  deduce that $$\sin \frac{\pi}{32}\sin \frac{2\pi}{32}\sin \frac{3\pi}{32}.........\sin \frac{15\pi}{32}=\frac{1}{2^{13}}$$

Can someone point me in the right direction with some explanation? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: We can get the second identity without the first immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A deduction from $x^n-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{(n-2)/2}[x^2-2x\cos{\frac{2k\pi}{n}}+1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735636/a-deduction-from-xn-1-x2-1-prod-k-1n-2-2x2-2x-cos-frac2k-pin) (Obtained from [Approach 0](http://45.79.98.50/demo/?q=%24%5Csin%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B32%7D%5Csin%20%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B32%7D%5Csin%20%5Cfrac%7B3%5Cpi%7D%7B32%7D.........%5Csin%20%5Cfrac%7B15%5Cpi%7D%7B32%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5E%7B13%7D%7D%24&p=1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing $n=32$, we can rewrite the equation like this:

$$\frac{x^{32}-1}{x^2-1} = \prod_{k=1}^{15}\left(x^2+1-2x\cos\frac{k\pi}{16}\right)$$
for all $x\neq\pm1$.

We will take the limit as $x\to 1$ of both sides of the equality.

First, we have (using L'Hôpital's rule)

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \frac{x^{32}-1}{x^2-1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac{32x^{31}}{2x} = 16$$

Then, plugging in $x=1$, we have
$$x^2+1-2x\cos\frac{k\pi}{16} = 2-2\cos\frac{k\pi}{16} = 4\cdot\frac{1-\cos(k\pi/16)}{2} = 4\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{32}$$

The product becomes
$$\prod_{k=1}^{15}4\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{32}= 4^{15}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{15}\sin\frac{k\pi}{32}\right)^2$$

Note that the limit as $x\to 1$ of the product is equal to its value at $x=1$ because the expression is continuous (it is the product of continuous functions).

Now, equating the limits we get

$$16 = 4^{15}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{15}\sin\frac{k\pi}{32}\right)^2$$

As all the factors in the product are positive, we can take the square root of both sides and we get

$$\sin \frac{\pi}{32}\sin \frac{2\pi}{32}\sin \frac{3\pi}{32}\cdots\sin \frac{15\pi}{32}= \prod_{k=1}^{15}\sin\frac{k\pi}{32} =\frac{1}{2^{13}}$$

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't use the given information, but it does give some intuition of what you are trying to show.

Consider $x^8 - 1$

The roots of unity are equally spaced around the unit circle.

[image]

$x^8-1 = (x-1)(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\cdots(x-r_7) = (x-1)(x^7 + x^6 + \cdots + 1)$

with $r_k = (\cos \frac {2k\pi}{8}, i\sin \frac{2k\pi}{8})$

$|(x^7 + x^6 + \cdots + 1)| = |x-r_1||x-r_2|\cdots|x-r_7|$

letting $x = 1$

$8 = |1-r_1||1-r_2|\cdots|1-r_7|$

$|1 - r_k| = 2\sin\frac {k\pi}{8}$  (highlighted in the figure for the case $k=3$)

$8 = 2^2\sin\frac {\pi}{8}\sin\frac {2\pi}{8}\sin\frac {5\pi}{8}\cdots\sin\frac {7\pi}{8}\\
\sin\frac {\pi}{8}\sin\frac {2\pi}{8}\cdots\sin\frac {7\pi}{8} = 2^{-4}$

Not a whole lot changes when we consider $x^{32} - 1$

Answer (score 2):

It is very straightforward to use complex numbers for this issue.

**Proof of the first formula (though not asked)** : Let $n=2m$.

The roots of $x^{2m}-1=0$ are the 2m-th roots of unity ; they can be written in the following way :

$$\omega_k=e^{ik \pi/m}, \ \ \ \ \ k=0,1,... (2m-1) $$

Thus, we can decompose:

$$x^{2m}-1=(x-\omega_0)(x-\omega_1) \cdots (x-\omega_{2m-1})\tag{1}$$

Let us group these factors 2 by 2 in this way :

$$(x-\omega_k)(x-\omega_{2m-k})=x^2-(e^{ik\pi/m }+e^{i(2m-k)\pi/m })x+ e^{i \pi k/m}.e^{i(2m-k)\pi/m}$$

which gives, knowing that $e^{2i\pi}=1,$

$$x^2-\underbrace{(e^{ik\pi/m }+e^{-ik\pi/m})}_{2 \cos(k\pi/m)}x+ 1 \tag{2}$$

using Euler formula.

Then it suffices to use (2) in (1)  giving identity

$$x^{2m}-1=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(x^2-2x\cos \frac{k\pi}{m}+1)\tag{3}$$

i.e., your identity, because the product of factors $(x-1)(x-(-1))=(w-\omega_0)(x-\omega_m)$ has been set apart.

**2nd formula** :

Factorizing $x$ in each 2nd degree factor on the RHS of (3) gives :

$$x^m(x^{m}-\tfrac{1}{x^m})=x^m(x-\tfrac{1}{x})\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(x-2\cos \frac{k\pi}{m}+\tfrac{1}{x})\tag{4}$$

Simplifying both sides by $x^{m}$, (4) becomes :

$$\frac{x^{m}-\tfrac{1}{x^m}}{x-\tfrac{1}{x}}=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}(x-2\cos \frac{k\pi}{m}+\tfrac{1}{x})\tag{5}$$

identity $\frac{a^m-b^m}{a-b}=a^{m-1}+a^{m-2}b+...+b^{m-1}$ ($m$ terms) allows us to write the LHS of (5) under the form

$$x^{m-1} + x^{m-3} + ... \tfrac{1}{x^{m-3}}+\tfrac{1}{x^{m-1}} \ \ (m \  \text{factors})$$

Let us now take $m=16$. Let $x$ tends to $1$,

- the LHS of (5) tends to $16=4^2$, whereas
- the RHS of (5) tends to the product of $m$ factors. Using classical formula $1-\cos2a=2 \sin^2a$, this RHS is equal to : 
  $$4^{15}\Pi_{k=1}^{15}(\sin^2(k\pi/32))$$

Equating RHS and LHS, and taking the square root of both sides, we get the desired formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , for your time and effort. Got it..

Comment: And there for you could upvote it @learner